# insert link on email message asp.net

Tags: asp.net, email, hyperlink

i want to insert a link or href maybe on this code:

```
MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("sender@gmail.com", txtEmail.Text.Trim());
            mm.Subject = "Password Recovery";
            mm.Body = string.Format("Hi {0},<br /><br />Click on the link to change your password.<br /><br />Thank You.<br/><br/>IslandGas Team", username);
            mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

after the word password, a link will be visible for a page redirect. please help me out.

UPDATE:

tried this but its not reading the aspx

```
mm.Body = string.Format("Hi {0},<br /><br />Click <a href='forgotpassword(link).aspx'> here</a> to change your password<br /><br />Thank You.<br/><br/>IslandGas Team", username);
```

Comment: You need to learn the basics of HTML.

Comment: can you help me out on this? @SLaks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Would be something like this, learn more about href [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp)

```
mm.Body = string.Format("Hi {0},<br /><br />Click <a href='http://www.YourWebSite.com'> here</a> to change your password<br /><br />Thank You.<br/><br/>IslandGas Team", username);
```

Comment: The href value needs to be the page you are linking to. If your forgot password page is forgotpassword.aspx and is in the same directory the href='forgotpassword.apsx'

Comment: yes but its not reading it. the link is not in the message sir

Comment: i mean its not redirecting

Comment: @Laslos: Emails cannot use relative URLs.

Comment: Doh... so @Paolo Duhaylungsod for the href put the URL for the password reset page.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a [hyperlink](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) in the body.
For example:

```
mm.Body = "Click <a href='http://google.com'>here</a> to change your password.";
```